# Jquery ajax cross site

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cross-platform

I have a ajax call from a remote site, when i test this on same site it works, when I call it from remote site, I get 200 OK but empty response.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getPage(storename,entries,page) {
    $('#output').html('<div class="centriraj"><span>Loading...</span><img id="loader" src="LoaderIcon.gif" /></div>');
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "http://jebajiga.byethost32.com/pager.php",
        crossOrigin: true,
        data:'page='+page+'&entries='+entries+'&storename='+storename,
       dataType: "html",
        type: "POST",
        success:function(data){$('#output').html(data);}

    });
}
getPage('cvsstarshop1991',30,1);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getListCategories(storename) {

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "http://jebajiga.byethost32.com/categories.php",
        crossOrigin: true,
        data:'storename='+storename,
       dataType: "html",
        type: "POST",
        success:function(data){$('#output2').html(data);}

    });
}
getListCategories('cvsstarshop1991');
</script>
```

Comment: does the server allow CORS?

Comment: It looks like you're calling these functions before the HTML DOM has been built. Perhaps the ajax call was successful but the output element hasn't been created yet. Try placing `getPage()` and `getCategories()` into `$(document).ready(function(){})` block.

Comment: any error you have in console, add that as well

Comment: (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Comment: @Toretto Any idea how to bypass this restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access data from a remote site using jquery/javascript the remote server must allow CORS. It's a security measure. 
If the server is yours, add the following into the page header outputs.

```
 if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
}
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
    }
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Is this on client side or side where I get data from? And where should I use this code? in php code?

Comment: That code will be helpful if implemented on the serverside

Comment: I added this piece of code to all remote php scripts.. still same..
"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://jebajiga.byethost32.com/pager.php. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
Line 0"

Comment: Found a solution.. you were right about this code.. only thing was.. my hosting didnt allowed any header change